# Where to hold Application Files - Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've got a docker host.  I've also got a container I created by running the run command..I didn't use a docker file yet, because I'm just not there yet, learning docker.

My question is if I'm planning on running an app in a container based off an ubuntu image, should I clone down my git file for that app from inside the container (when I'm bashed into it interactively) or should the container somehow read the files from the docker host and therefore clone my files down to a directory on the docker host instead?  How are containers supposed to work with respect to running the app files and where those files should be cloned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't use a docker file yet, because I'm just not there yet, learning docker.

This is a mistake. A docker container is not a VM. Actually creating an image and running containers from that image is what docker is about. The [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is a quite readable introduction with some excellent, simple, examples at the bottom.

That being said: If this is your code then it can live wherever you build your docker image from, then in the Dockerfile use `ADD` to copy your code (or binaries) into the image (if you're developing your app and using the container for testing then using `VOLUME` to mount the app in is common).

If this is "just some git repo" and you simply want to build it into the image you could use `RUN git clone` in the Dockerfile the same way you'd use `git clone` locally (assuming your image already has `git` in it, and if it doesn't just use a `RUN` command to install `git` like you would normally--though you'll generally want to make sure to pass `-y` or `--noconfirm` or whatever the OS package manager takes for a
'don't ask me, just do it' flag).

A Dockerfile is just a list of steps to build an OS image: if you can do it in a VM running that OS you can do it with a `RUN` in the Dockerfile: if the source is in git you can `git clone` (and if it's source that needs to be compiled you could even run the compile right in your Dockerfile), or if it's distributed as a zip you could simply `curl` and install.

I don't have an example of a Dockerfile doing a clone, but to show you some of what you can do in a Dockerfile here's one of mine which installs `tar` with the OS package manager, then downloads and installs `java` via `curl` and the OS package manager, and then downloads and unpacks two tarred archives:

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN set -x             && \
    yum install -y tar && \
    yum clean all

RUN set -x       && \
    curl -sOL 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm' \
         -H 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' && \
    rpm -i jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm && \
    rm jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm && \
    echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/' >> ~/.bashrc

ENV HBASE_VERSION 0.94.24
RUN set -x         && \
    curl -L http://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/hbase-$HBASE_VERSION/hbase-$HBASE_VERSION.tar.gz | \
    tar zvx --null && \
    echo "export HBASE_HOME=/hbase-$HBASE_VERSION" >> ~/.bashrc

ADD hbase-site.xml /hbase-$HBASE_VERSION/conf/hbase-site.xml
ADD run.sh /hbase-$HBASE_VERSION/bin/LOCAL-run.sh

ENV PHOENIX_VERSION 3.2.0
RUN set -x && \
    curl -L http://archive.apache.org/dist/phoenix/phoenix-$PHOENIX_VERSION/bin/phoenix-$PHOENIX_VERSION-bin.tar.gz | \
    tar zvx --null && \
    cp /phoenix-$PHOENIX_VERSION-bin/common/phoenix-core-$PHOENIX_VERSION.jar /hbase-$HBASE_VERSION/lib/


CMD ["/hbase-0.94.24/bin/LOCAL-run.sh"]
```

Comment: yea I've read all that, I misunderstood containers a bit.  Thanks

Comment: yea so wherever you build your docker image from is typically from your docker host vm I think

Comment: so ultimately, you're saying for an app that lives in github, I'd clone it to my host.  Then in the docker file, ADD it and so the container has a copy of the code in that path.  Makese sense because if code changed on the host, it wouldn't affect my container that I'm testing with because it has a COPY of the files at a certain time.

Comment: If the code isn't yours and you're literally just going to clone it for the build you could just make sure that `git` is installed in the image (add `RUN apt-get install -y git` to your Dockerfile if the ubuntu image doesn't have it already) and just add a `RUN` to your Dockerfile with your `git clone` command. Dockerfile is very similar in many ways to Makefile and anything you can do locally could be done at build time if that suits your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can run container by providing `-v` option to run command as
`$ docker run -v <path on host> : <path inside container> <image name>`
This will mount the path inside the container to the path on the host.
Regarding app files to clone, exploring [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is good one. The `ADD` option will solve your issue.

Comment: do people normally just map to code cloned down to host for example with Git or do they clone files down to the container's filesystem?  Just wanted to know good practice or what normally people do out there or if it even makes good sense to try to clone it down into the container at all

Comment: thanks for this, I could also just play around with this too, if I don't want to get to creating my docker file just yet.  Just get the app working by having the container talk to the mounted path first.  Then proceed on creating a dockerfile and doing it right.

Comment: Unless you're actively developing the code and using the container to test it (such as having apache run in the container and modifying some web code on your local filesystem) it's an anti-pattern to volume-mount code into a container.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the app from within the container or copy it (use COPY not ADD unless you have a good reason https://labs.ctl.io/dockerfile-add-vs-copy/) during the build process. They are both valid ways to do it.

The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve from that container. Is creating a new container something you'll do occasionally or frequently. Will you be sharing this image at some point of time with others? Dockerfiles are great for repeatable tasks. Each time you build it will create an image with the same consistent steps. I would recommend learning to write a Dockerfile as part of your leaning.

You could of course do the setup once manually inside the container then commit and push it. That way you (or someone else) can pull it again later and continue from that point. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/